# How do I find the geographic mean of a multipoint feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, maps

[image]

I'm trying to find the geographic mean of the multipoint feature in the above image. It seems like a really simple command, but I cannot find any way to do it.

Comment: [Centroid?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of accomplishing this.

For SQL, see https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html.

```
Select st_centroid(geom) as geom from table
```

For a point collection (rather than a multipoint), use:

```
select st_centroid(st_collect(geom))
from table
```

Also, there's a Geometric Median function, which is useful on messy data with extreme outliers https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometricMedian.html.

And as per Erik's comment, there's also this method in the Field Calculator:

```
centroid($geometry)
```

[image]

And this one, in the Vector - Geometry menu:

[image]

Comment: No need to use SQL, this can be simply done using the GUI tool `centroid`.

Comment: Or `centroid ($geometry)` with QGIS epxressions (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)